# Any small bags that mount to seat post?

Tags: bags

I am looking for something similar to a saddle bag but that mounts to the seat post and not the saddle.

I have a rear mounted camera that attaches to the saddle so want a bag that I can mount lower down on the seat post. I want to keep tubes, CO2, multitool etcetera in there.

I have searched and can't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: The first search result was Ortlieb Seatpost-Bag, does it suit your needs?

Comment: I saw that but its massive! I just need enough room for a spare tube and a multitool really.

Comment: You could (almost) always use a triangle bag or a top-tube bag.  My tube, tools and minor first aid kit fit in a top tube bag designed for a smartphone (I carry a pump on the frame, but removing the first aid kit should make room for a CO2 kit).

Comment: I have tried both of those. The triangle bag makes it hard to get the water bottle out. The top tube bag always slips to the side (my top tube is thin so bag straps cannot be tightened)

Comment: It's not what you're asking for, but I carry 2 tubes, puncture kit, 3 levers and multi-tool wrapped neatly in a plastic bag I put in my center rear pocket. I slip my mobile phone in there too.

Comment: I want something that stays on the bike so I can't forget it. Thanks for all the suggestions but not solved it yet!

Comment: Might be easier to find a seat post camera mount and use a standard saddle bag

Comment: What about http://www.topeak.com/products/Bottle-Cage-Bag

Comment: Yes, I am starting to think that a tool bottle is the way to go... For long rides I can revert to a proper saddle bag as I will not have camera then. Thanks.

Comment: Another solution is to cut a small section of a dead tube to make a pouch for multi tool and CO2, then wrap a new tube around it and tape it to the seat post with a length of thick pvc tape. I carry extra tubes and stuff like that so I can get away with only the smallest water pack on long mtb rides. Doesn't rattle on come open like a saddle bag. I used to use a saddle bag but ended up taping that on and shut anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of [Revelate Designs Jerry Can](https://www.revelatedesigns.com/index.cfm/store.catalog/Cockpit/Jerrycan) bags would work for you.  The mount on the front side of the seatpost and would leave the rear of your seat post open for your camera.  They are pretty versatile, I have used one on top of the triangle, inside the triangle and a few other places I won't mention.

Comment: Not 100% what I was looking for but pretty good solution and I think the closest I will get to what I was asking for. I think that I will actually go for a tool bottle instead though.

Comment: I've been pretty happy with mine.  Easily moved from bike to bike and several mounting options.  I sometimes forget about water bottles because so many of my bikes have frame bags.